# How to fix a dead code warning in a boolean method? (i++)

Tags: java

I'm working on a hangman game, and this boolean statement will not run due to an i++ being dead code. Here's the affected piece of code.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman { 

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
char[] word;
char[] userInputs;
int lengthofWord;

boolean isIn(char c, char[] word) {
    lengthofWord = word.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthofWord; i++) {
        if(word[i] == c) {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't return in both the `if` **and** `else`. Your loop currently doesn't. Also, your logic looks backwards. Assuming you want to return `true` when the `char c` appears in the `word` you needed something like,

```
boolean isIn(char c, char[] word)
{
    int lengthofWord = word.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthofWord; i++) {
        if (word[i] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**or** you could write it with a `for-each` loop like

```
boolean isIn(char c, char[] word)
{
    for (char a : word) {
        if (a == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `i++` is of no use is that you are `return`ing after comparing the first character anyhow since both the `if` and `else` has a `return` statement.

You can simplify your method as corrected by Elliott in their answer and further update it as:

```
boolean isIn(char c, char[] word) {
    return IntStream.range(0, word.length).noneMatch(i -> word[i] == c);
}
```

or by the name of the method, it should logically be *if any of the characters are in the array*, then use

```
boolean isIn(char c, char[] word) {
    return IntStream.range(0, word.length).anyMatch(i -> word[i] == c);
}
```